# How to split dataframe for scikit

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a big dataframe, how can I divide it into 80% and 20% for test and train
Thanks!

I tried split but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = #define X columns
y = #defone y columns(target)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
```

X_train and y_train, which contain 80% of the data, and X_test and y_test, which contain the remaining 20%